# 1 pixel vertical discrepancy between text on OSX and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, html, css

I have a pretty simple button that is marked up like this:

```
<a href="#" class="common_cta buttons send_inquiry">
    <span>Back to homepage</span>
</a>
```

The computed style of the `<a>` element looks like this: http://pastebin.com/u9q6BDHx

The computed style of the `<span>` looks like this: http://pastebin.com/P9mR7yHF

Here's what it looks like in comparison, Windows vs. OSX:

[image]

As you can see, there's a one pixel discrepancy between Windows and everything else. The designers are requiring that this be a pixel-perfect implementation and I have no idea how to fix the problem specifically for OSX.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might try setting the `line-height` of the `<a>` element to match the `<span>` (24px)

Comment: @steveax Just tried it, no difference at all.

Comment: It's the way that OSX is rendering the text compared to XP.  Unless you want to style per browser you could always just change the whole button into a graphic, otherwise it is really tough to implement a perfect browser comparison.

Comment: Probably has to do with the different font-smoothing schemes then. Not sure there's a fix then other than what Lazerblade mentions (although that way lies madness at the end). What browsers are the screenshots from?

Comment: Browsers are Firefox on OSX and Chrome on XP. Browsers don't really seem to make a difference, it seems like the way that each OS handles fonts. I'll ask if I can bake it, otherwise I'll have to `.mac { padding-top: 1px; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oYou're going to find that every browser will differ at least slightly in how it handles CSS. For instance, my company's website uses some crazy SEO "tricks" to get sections higher in the page as viewed by Goggle vs. where a user sees the info. As a result, some of the CSS I write requires browser-specific tweaks.

I believe what you're looking for is something along the lines of the following, allowing individual styles per browser to be used:

```
.win.ie .buttons {padding:3px 5px;}
.mac.gecko .buttons {padding:4px 5px;}
.chrome .buttons {padding:4px 6px;}
.win.gecko .buttons{padding:4x 6px;}
```